# Take input as a row from user

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

a = InputBox("Enter the Row", "Excel VBA Says", "Please enter data")
    Rows("a").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("L8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Rows("a" + 1).Select
    Selection.Rows.Group
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    
End Sub
```

Im getting an error at Rows("a").Select can someone help me correct it

Comment: `a` is a variable, so you do not put quotes around it. Also, what happens if the user types a number less than one or an alpha character in the input box?

Comment: `Rows(a).Select` - assuming `a` is a number greater than `0`.

Comment: @braX Yes I think ill have to put some error handlers and validation also one of the issue was I guess I havent defined a as Integer what I did firstly I defined a as an integer and then I used Rows(a).Select, Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'd use `Application.Inputbox` and let the user actually pick a range.

Comment: If you are going to use `a` as a row variable, you should use a `Long` and not an `Integer`

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for the suggestion will update it.

Comment: Hi @braX, Can you help me with the Range Part Im trying to delete the contents of cell as well suppose Rows = 10 then i want to delete the contents of L10

Comment: Consider using Rows(a).Select instead of Rows("a").Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ref to your deleted answer, you should always declare variables of `InputBox` as `String`. Then you can perform your validation. In your case you simply do something like this:

```
  Dim a As String
  a = InputBox("Enter the Row", "Excel VBA Says", "Please enter data")
  If Not IsNumeric(a) Or Val(a) <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid row number"
  Else
    Rows(a).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range("L" & a).ClearContents
        Rows(a + 1).Select
        Selection.Rows.Group
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
  End If
```

Edit: added check for `a`=0 following comments

Comment: Hi @Super Symmetry, Can you help me with the Range Part Im trying to delete the contents of cell as well suppose Rows = 10 then i want to delete the contents of L10

Comment: Thanks a ton @Super Symmetry

Comment: You're welcome. As I had a final look at the code I found a small bug, where the user was able to enter a negative number. So I changed `Val(a) = 0` to `Val(a) <= 0`. All the best